# c# - 'inherit' current property values from default object instance

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, clone

I have a factory class Factory that spits out instances of the Document class. When the factory is instantiated it creates an instance of the Settings class and stores the reference in the defaultSettings property. Then the factory calls the defaultSettings.getDefaults() method which loads the default settings from the database.

Each Document instance created by the factory should get his own instance of the Settings class with the default property values as they are in the defaultSettings property in the Factory (as in a clone). The Factory can call getDefaults() multiple times to update the default settings; during the program lifetime 100 douments can be created and the factory might have updated its default settings 3 times.

The Document instances can then modify their own properties when they want, without obviously modifying the default settings.

```
public class Document
{
    Settings mySettings;
    public Document(Settings defaultSettings)
    {
        mySettings = defaultSettings;
    }
    public void updateRead(bool Option)
    {
        mySettings.canRead = Option;
    }
}

public class Settings
{
    public bool canRead;
    public bool canWrite;

    public void getDeafult()
    {
        canWrite = // Expensive DB call
    }
}

public class Factory
{
    Settings defaultSettings;

    public Factory()
    {
        defaultSettings = new Settings();
        defaultSettings.getDeafult();
    }

    public Document createDocument()
    {
        // Create a settings instance with the current default values
        // and instantiate a document with these settings
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this, without using Reflection? It seems this is a logical thing to do.. Is there a proper Design pattern for this, or is there a better alternative for settings this up?

Comment: Might want to post it here too if you're asking about best practice: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: the factory has to be static class, are the default settings always same? you can make a copy of default setting (initialized once from DB) over and over and feed them to your documents.

Comment: Can you cache the default settings or does it have to be read from the DB every time a new document is created?

Comment: @InBetween: During the lifetime 100 douments can be created and the factory might have updated its defaultsettings 3 times, so its unrelated. The whole idea is that I hope i can have the defaultSettings instance hold the cache values

Comment: I'm not understanding you. What is completely unrelated? If the default settings can be updated while you are creating documents, how exactly is your caching strategy? How do you ensure that your cached defaults are not stale?

Comment: @InBetween; this is an addin. The factory gets called when data is updated in the program that holds the addin. I have no control over that.